# Referencing an attribute within a method

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, class, attributes

Is it bad practice to reference an attribute with a new variable name in a method within a class? For example:

```
class Stuff:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def some_method(self):
        a = self.a
        # Do some stuff with a
```

I've seen this in other peoples' code and I've gotten into a habit of it myself, especially with long variable names. It seems like a copy of `a` is created when I do this which could be a problem if `a` is very large. Should I just stick to calling `self.a` inside of `some_method`? Does python garbage collect the `a` created in `some_method` after it is called?

Comment: Side-note: What you're referencing is an _attribute_, not a _property_. [Python's properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) are methods that act like attributes. And in fact, if it really were a property, caching to a local name might make more sense (assuming the property is idempotent, so repeated access isn't important to code logic), since it would avoid invoking the method over and over. properties are, by convention, fairly cheap to call, but it's still a lot more expensive (relatively speaking, though not on an absolute scale) that simple attribute access.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't necessarily a bad practice, you could make this assignment with two reasons (see the comments by @ShadowRanger for a quite obscure third reason) backing it:

- Making code more readable (as you mentioned, long names can be *too* long.
- Eliminating the dot; if you have a tedious loop that uses `self.a`, it might shed some time if you don't need to perform the look-up every time (not *too much* time, though). Additionally, if this wasn't a plain attribute but instead was a function, assigning it to a local variable would eliminate the transformation from `function` to `method` which also sheds some execution time.

Also, copy isn't the best term, you just make a different name refer to the same object. After the method `some_method` is completed, `a` will just not exist because it is only created in the local scope.

No, garbage collection doesn't happen because `a` (which is assigned to the value of `self.a`) isn't the only reference; you still have `self.a` which keeps the value assigned to it alive.

Comment: assigning to new variable may not be good idea if it has text or number (int, float) and you what to assign new value to local variable and you expect the same value in `self.` variable.

Comment: A third reason to do the assignment is to get "consistent reads" in a multithreaded scenario. If `a` is immutable, but `self.a` could be reassigned at any time, and `some_method` depends on a consistent (but not necessarily current) value of `a`, reading once into a local name and only using the local name ensures you get consistency, without additional locking, at the expense of possible staleness.

Comment: @ShadowRanger can't say I've bumped into that scenario but, your explanation makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard: It doesn't come up all that much largely because CPU bound threading is kind of terrible in the CPython reference interpreter, thanks to the GIL. But I've had projects that were largely doing I/O and GIL-releasing C extension work, where threading actually was helpful, and occasionally used more advanced versions of tricks like this. Not pretty, and dangerous if you don't understand the GIL _very_ well, but it's occasionally useful.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. @JimFasarakis-Hilliard if its not a copy but you're only manipulating it in local scope, what is it then? Why doesn't the class's attribute get affected if its manipulated in the method?

Comment: @KenMyers If the value passed to `self.a` in `__init__` is mutable, changes to it via `a` in `some_method` *will* be reflected. I argued for the term "copy" since it implies an object gets copied and re-assigned. In python names act like labels to objects, so doing `a = self.a` simply means add the label `a` to whatever value `self.a` has. That way you can reference the same value via `self.a` or `a`. If an object is immutable and you change `a` then no changes will be reflected to `self.a`.